# Is it possible to install solaris 11 with zfs root file system in virtual box guest?

Tags: virtualbox, solaris, zfs

I want to test zfs file sharing capabilities using a virtual machine. Is this possible because I don't seem to get a prompt during installation to select a zfs file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris 11 does not ask you if you want ZFS root because it has no other choice - only ZFS root is supported for Solaris 11 installs - UFS is relegated to supporting data disks only.

See [Oracle Solaris 11 File System Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E36219/filesystem-10.html) for more details.

Comment: Yup, I eventually figured that out... A bit like looking for your glasses when they are on your face !